# How to handle refresh token requests with ReactJS, node server and nginx proxy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx, spotify, refresh-token

> Background

My dockerized app requires User Authorizaton in order to fetch his data from Spotify.

For that I'm using Auhtorization Code, which needs server-to-server data exchange, that is: I make requests to Spotify's account services from a backend server, and not from my Client.

Examples of how to fetch access token are found everywhere, but I haven'f found any example of how to get another access token after the first expires, using the refresh token.

The Authorization Code schema:

[image]

---

> My server

To implement that flow, I have build a node backend service behind a `nginx proxy`, like so:

**dev.conf**

```
server {

listen  8888;

    location / {
        proxy_pass        http://spotify-server:8888;
        proxy_redirect    default;
        proxy_set_header  Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header  Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header  Host $host;
        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
        proxy_send_timeout 86400s;
    }
}
```

Structure at host:

```
client/...
      src/...
         AuthorizationCode.jsx
nginx/...
     dev.conf
web/...
spotify-server/
              server.js
              public/
                    index.html
```

I have all set up and working to stage (3) above.

Thus, I'm being able to get an access token and a refresh token, to be used after 60 minutes.

---

> Frontend

I call my redirect page from Spotify at my `React` frontend:

**AuthorizationCode.jsx**

```
onClick={() => window.location = 'http://localhost:8888'
```

This pings the authorization back to `/callback` at server, which on its turn redirects me from backend to my frontend at 'http://localhost/#', with both tokens:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const params = this.getHashParams();
    const access_token = params.access_token
    const refresh_token = params.refresh_token
    localStorage.setItem('spotifyAuthToken', access_token);
    localStorage.getItem('spotifyAuthToken');
  }
```

The above works.

---

> Server Code:

Now this is my **server.js** code:

```
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
   .use(cors())
   .use(cookieParser());

app.get('/login', function(req, res) {

  var state = generateRandomString(16);
  res.cookie(stateKey, state);

  // your application requests authorization -------------> STEP 1
  var scope = Credentials.scope;
  res.redirect('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?' +
    querystring.stringify({
      response_type: 'code',
      client_id: client_id,
      scope: scope,
      redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
      state: state
    }));
});

app.get('/callback', function(req, res) {   

  // your application requests refresh and access tokens
  // after checking the state parameter

  var code = req.query.code || null;
  var state = req.query.state || null;
  var storedState = req.cookies ? req.cookies[stateKey] : null;

  if (state === null || state !== storedState) {
    res.redirect('/#' +
      querystring.stringify({
        error: 'state_mismatch'
      }));
  } else {
    res.clearCookie(stateKey);
    var authOptions = {
      url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', //--------------> STEP 2
      form: {
        code: code,
        redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
        grant_type: 'authorization_code'
      },
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64'))
      },
      json: true
    };

    request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

        var access_token = body.access_token,
            refresh_token = body.refresh_token;

        var options = {
          url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me',
          headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token },
          json: true
        };

        // use the access token to access the Spotify Web API
        request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
          console.log(body);
        });

        // we can also pass the token to the browser to make requests from there
        res.redirect('http://localhost/#' + //--------------> STEP 2 
          querystring.stringify({
            access_token: access_token,
            refresh_token: refresh_token
          }));
      } else {
        res.redirect('/#' +
          querystring.stringify({
            error: 'invalid_token'
          }));
      }
    });
  }
});
```

---

And this is the point where I'm trying to wrap my head around: how to POST and GET a new access token to my server, from my frontend.

```
app.get('/refresh_token', function(req, res) { --------------> STEP 4

  // requesting access token from refresh token
  var refresh_token = req.query.refresh_token;
  var authOptions = {
    url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64')) },
    form: {
      grant_type: 'refresh_token',
      refresh_token: refresh_token
    },
    json: true
  };

  request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      var access_token = body.access_token;
      res.send({
        'access_token': access_token
      });
    }
  });
});

console.log('Listening on 8888');
app.listen(8888);
```

---

I have tried:

```
handleRefreshToken(event) {

const {token} = this.state.spotifyRefreshToken
const options = {
  url: 'http://localhost:8888/refresh_token',
  method: 'get',
  data: token,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': true,
     Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`
  }
};
return axios(options)
.then((res) => {
  //console.log('getBaristaCoffee() --->', res.data.data)
  console.log()
  this.setState({
  })
})    
.catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
```

};

with:

```
onClick={(event) => this.handleRefreshToken(event)}
```

but I get the error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8888/refresh_token' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

and then:

```
GET http://localhost:8888/refresh_token net::ERR_FAILED
```

`nginx` service logs throws me a 499 Error, usually caused by client side timeout:

```
nginx_2 | 172.18.0.1 - - [07/Mar/2020:21:56:12 +0000] "GET /refresh_token HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx_2 | 2020/03/07 21:57:12 [error] 6#6: *186 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: <my_ip>, server: , request: "GET /refresh_token HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://<my_ip>:8888/refresh_token", host: "localhost:8888", referrer: "http://localhost/"
nginx_2 | 172.18.0.1 - - [07/Mar/2020:21:57:12 +0000] "GET /refresh_token HTTP/1.1" 502 559 "http://localhost/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx_2 | 172.18.0.1 - - [07/Mar/2020:21:59:24 +0000] "GET /refresh_token HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx_2 | 172.18.0.1 - - [07/Mar/2020:21:59:57 +0000] "GET /refresh_token HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

---

**QUESTION**

How do I implement a call to '/refresh_token' at my backend from my Frontend, passing my refresh token and getting a new access token?

**BONUS**

A watcher function to track access token expire time of 3600 would get a 50 bounty.

Comment: The first thing seems wrong to me is that your front end does `POST /refresh_token`, and your back end expects `GET /refresh_token`.

Comment: CORS needs to be allowed on the server.  and it's not really clear here but are there two servers on localhost (one 8888 and the other 80 i assume)?  or are you just running some random development server for react while using the 8888 as the actual server?  if your only problem here is CORS you can either enable it in node with the `cors` pkg or just serve the react page from it.

Comment: I have another server with Flask, for service Web. That is exposed to 80. Maybe I should implement refresh oauth directly there with python, using the server already there. But my flow was developed with Inplicit Flow up to now which uses JavaScript at client. I will probably develop both options.

Comment: By the way, Cors is already enabled in my node server.js